# How to include boost::future in CMake?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, future

I want to use `boost::future` in my C++ code:

```
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
boost::future<int> f...
```

Just including the header in the `C++` file gives a compilation error:

```
error: ‘future’ in namespace ‘boost’ does not name a template type
```

so I tried to include `future` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

`find_package(Boost COMPONENTS future REQUIRED)`

However, the `make` command returns an error:

`CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
 Could NOT find Boost (missing: future) (found version "1.71.0")`

So how to include future from boost?

Comment: I suppose Boost future is a header only library. Boost header only libraries do not need to be included int the `COMPONENTS` section of `find_package` call.

Comment: You only need to add Boost components to `find_package`, which are actual libraries. But many components of Boost are header-only, so you can just include the header in your source code and use it.

Comment: @vre @Simon, you mean `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS)`? If I do that the C++ code does not compile: `error: ‘future’ in namespace ‘boost’ does not name a template type`

Comment: you still need to include the future header in  your code

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I edited the question, it is included...

Comment: What are the commands generated by CMake? Can you reproduce this without CMake? What is the [mcve] that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
```

This is documented [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/thread/build.html#thread.build.configuration.future)

So you can either use:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
boost::future<int> f;
```

Or:

```
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
boost::unique_future<int> f;
```

Or:

```
// any version >= 3 will work
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 5
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
boost::future<int> f;
```